# Issue with loading data into Parquet table from a JSON Serde based Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, shark-sql, parquet

I have a `HIVE` table defined using a `JSON Serde`. I'm using the `Shark` distribution (http://shark.cs.berkeley.edu/). The definition is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE lastfm(
artist string,
title string ,
track_id string,
similars array<array<string>>,
tags array<array<string>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe';
```

I am able to successfully load data into this table. Now, I created a `Parquet` based table in `HIVE`.

```
CREATE TABLE lastfm_par (
  artist string,
  title string ,
    track_id string,
    similars array<array<string>>,
    tags array<array<string>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'parquet.hive.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
 STORED AS
 INPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat'
 OUTPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetOutputFormat';
```

Now, I try to load the data from the `JSON Serde` table to the `Parquet` one using the following command:

```
insert overwrite table lastfm_par select * from lastfm;
```

The `insert` statement is completes successfully. But when I query the data in the `Parquet` table, all the columns are populated with `NULL` values. I searched for similar issues online, but haven't seen anything similar yet. Does anyone have some thoughts on what's going wrong here?

Thanks,
Visakh